# where is the displacment and bump option in 2.83

Tags: materials

[image]

I cannot find the displacment and bump option in the new blender2.83

Answer (score 2):

You're looking in the right place but displacement is only available in Cycles - not Eevee. You need to change your Render Engine to Cycles to see those options.